# Debian server seems to use more and more swap

Tags: memory, debian, swap

I've got a problem with my debian server. It has 4GB of ram and 1GB swap. Swap is around 95% full and ram still has 80% left. I'm running lighttpd (max 40 users at the same time) and some gameservers (VALVe games) on it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you run [top](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_(software)) on your server to check what is using the swap space? A more in-depth alternative is [htop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htop_(Unix)).

Comment: Top helped us much finding the bad guy. It was `hlstats`. A statistics plugin we don't use anymore. After killing the process, we won a huge amount of swap again. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

Does the system feel slow?

Maybe Linux sees that some of your servers are not in use and swaps them out to have more space for the running servers.

If you want more of your data in the ram, then you can try to change the value of Swapiness: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swappiness

Comment: Well, all servers are well visited and no, it doesn't feel slow, but we have lost packets, when Swap is (soon to be) full.